# How to check whether the data is coming from different fragment.

Tags: android-fragments

I have 4 fragments and attaching to single grid adapter how to check from which fragment it is coming.

Comment: Without more informations, it might be difficult to correctly understand your problem. You should had your adapter or expand a little bit on your architecture. That being said, (assuming that I understand correctly, you have an adapter which contains 4 fragments, so) I guess you could use the adapter items position to retrieve which fragment is visible on screen?

Comment: just think i have four fragments(tabs) morning,afternoon,evening,night iam passing arraylist from 4 fragments.for fragments iam using single baseAdapter so i have to test in adapter that data is coming from which fragments and based on that i have to do something.

Comment: OK, then what about a simple solution by passing an integer in the constructor's adapter which contains the index of fragment's origin (example 0=morning, 1=afternoon, etc)? You could initialize the adapter as `new MyAdapter(1, myList);`.